# Django Admin Tabural Inline Throwing Error

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have created a Category and Product model when In the product model I have created a category field which is foreign key relation to the category model.

```
class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
icon= models.ImageField(upload_to='CategoryIcons/', blank=True, null=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Here is the Product Model -

```
class Product(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
productImages = models.ManyToManyField(ProductImages)
price = models.IntegerField()
qty = models.IntegerField(default=0)
shortDescription = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.title}{ self.category}'
```

Now when I try to use Django tabural Inline class with it says
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

**ERRORS:
<class 'shop.admin.CategoryInline'>: (admin.E202) 'shop.Category' has no ForeignKey to 'shop.Product'**.

admin.py file code -

```
    from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, ProductImages, Product, Order, Shipping, OrderItem

# Register your models here.

class CategoryInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Category
    readonly_fields = ('id', 'created_at')
    extra = 2


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ CategoryInline, ]
    
admin.site.register(Category)
admin.site.register(ProductImages )
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
admin.site.register(Order)
admin.site.register(Shipping)
admin.site.register(OrderItem)
```

I am confused that where I am doing wrong as in most of the places I see the same formate and code. Please help me out.

Comment: "'shop.Category' has no ForeignKey to 'shop.Product'" - 

Product has an FK to Category, instead of the other way around. Which means a product has one category and a category have zero, one or multiple products.

However, the way you set up your inline makes it so you could choose multiple categories for every single product. Since this is not reflected in the models/database, you get an error.

Comment: This is confusing sir, what should be the possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Category` is a ForeignKey to `Product`, not the other way around, that is why you are getting the error. Instead, you can show the products inside the Category Adminsite, like this:

```
class ProductInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Product
    readonly_fields = ('id', 'created_at')
    extra = 2


class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ ProductInline, ]
    
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

***Or,*** you can define the relation between `Product` to `Category` as ManyToMany, then the inline functionality should work. In that case the implementation should be like this:

```
#model
class Product(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

#admin

from django.contrib import admin

class CategoryInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Product.categories.through

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        CategoryInline,
    ]
```

ManyToMany relation sounds more logical because one product can have multiple categories, similarly one category can have multiple products. More information can be found regarding admin site implementation in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models).

Comment: thank you, sir, the first part works perfectly.